# Create additional calendar in MS Outlook 2010 programatically without MS Exchange account

Tags: outlook-addin, pop3, outlook-2010, outlook-calendar

If you're using MS Outlook with MS Mail Exchange account, you're able to either share your calendar to other or to be shared by other. Otherwise, if you're using it with any other type of account (*POP3, for instance*), those features are not available.

I'm being assigned a task that is to create additional calendar by programing in Visual Studio 2010 using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` library. Please notice that we're using POP3 mail server.

Please refer to this image: 
[image]

Without using MS Exchange account, am I able to create additional calendar by programming in VS 2010 using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` library?